# Weasyprint - Background-Color for <td>-element on pagebreaks

Tags: html, css, background-color, weasyprint

I've got a really weird problem with the background-color of an `<td>` element that has a page-break inside their rowspan. As you can see in the screenshots it should render the background-color on both pages, it just doesn't do it. Sometimes it overflows onto the footer-area, sometimes it doesn't even fill out the whole column on the first page. (View images to see what I mean)

[not enough background-color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9YJU.png)

[overflowing color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIh3h.png)

Also weird is that it seems to be handled diffently in some cases (overflowing & not filling out the whole column), not sure what the difference between this two shown behaviors is. I'll add the html-template file and css used to generate the table. For the html of the specific table shown in the screenshots please visit the same/similar issue I posted here at [Github Weasyprint](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1102), cause the character limitation didn't let me here because it's so big...

Also a similar problem is happening with text, it's also overflowing like the color:
[overflowing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk5gK.png)

Hopefully someone has an idea what I can do about it, I'm really stuck right now.

And another question: is there any way to add a bottom-border to the last row of the table on a page and rerender the text inside on the next page again?

Before someone mentions the `page-break-inside: avoid`-attribute, I'm familiar with that, the problem is it can't help me, because some of the sections in this table are way bigger than one page (maybe not with this data but it is possible and does happen) so I just can't keep the sections together and break afterwards.

Appreciate every comment that could help me!

CSS:

```
    general_css = weasyprint.CSS(
        string='''
            @page {
              size: A4 landscape;
              margin: 4cm 0.5cm 1cm 0.5cm;

              @bottom-right {
                content: "Seite " counter(page) " von " counter(pages);
                font-family: "Arial" !important;
                font-size: 9px !important;
                padding-right: 24px;
                padding-bottom: 7px;
              }
            }
            @page:first {
              margin: 2.5cm 0.5cm 1cm 0.5cm;
            }

            header {
              width: 98.5%;
              top: 0;

            }
            header:not(.first-page-header) {
              height: 3.4cm;
              max-height: 3.4cm;
              margin: auto;
              margin-top: -3.4cm;
              position: fixed;
            }
            /*
             * The header for all other pages is positioned fixed, thus is also present at the first page.
             * With the use of z-index and a pseudo-element that header is covered by the header of the title-page.
             */
            header.first-page-header {
              background-color: white;
              margin-top: -1.8cm;
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 10;
            }
            header.first-page-header:after {
              background-color: white;
              content: '';
              width: 100%;
              height: 1cm;
              border-right: 2px solid white;
              border-left: 2px solid white;
              box-sizing: content-box;
              top: -1cm;
              position: absolute;
            }

            footer {
              font-size: 9px;
              text-align: right;
              left: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              position: fixed;
              height: 0.5cm;
              padding-left: 24px;
              margin-bottom: -0.8cm;
            }

            body {
              font-family: "Arial" !important;
              font-style: "normal";
              font-size: 9px;
            }
            body * {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            table {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 100%;
              page-break-inside: auto;
            }

            tr {
              page-break-inside:auto;
              break-inside:auto;
              page-break-after:auto;
            }

            table,
            th,
            td {
              page-break-inside: auto;
              break-inside: auto;
              page-break-after: auto;
            }

            th,
            td {
              border: 1px solid black;
            }

            th {
              padding: 4px;
            }

            td {
              vertical-align:top;
            }

            h2 {
              font-size: 14px;
            }

            h3 {
              font-size: 12px;
            }

            p {
              font-size: 10px;
            }

            .header-container td > p,
            h2,
            h3,
            img {
              margin: 0 ;
            }

            li > p {
              text-decoration: underline;
            }

            .title-container {
              height: 600px;
              padding-top: 5px;
              border: 1px solid black;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: row;
            }

            ol {
              padding-left: 16px;
              margin-left: 16px;
            }

            ol > li {
              font-size: 12px;
            }

            .alt:before {
              background-color:red;
            }

            .pink-box {
              background-color: #ec0bc7;
              width: 100%;
              min-height: 1.2mm;
              border-right: 1px solid black;
              border-left: 1px solid black;
            }
        ''')

[...]
    document = weasyprint.HTML(
            string=rendered_template_1+rendered_template_2,
            url_fetcher=url_fetcher
        ).render(stylesheets=[general_css])
```

Table-Template-File:

```
{% load get_protective_measures_count_with_same_danger_id %}
{% load order_protective_measures_by_danger_id_and_risk %}

<table style="width: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
    {% for assessment_activity in assessment_activities %}

    {% order_protective_measures_by_danger_id_and_risk assessment_activity.assessment_protective_measures.all as assessment_protective_measures %}

    {% for assessment_protective_measure in assessment_protective_measures %}
      <tr>
        {% if forloop.first %}
          <td
            rowspan="{{ assessment_activity.assessment_protective_measures.all.count }}"
            style="padding: 4px; max-width: 165px; width: 164px;"
          >
            {{ assessment_activity.activity.name }}
          </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% ifchanged assessment_protective_measure.danger.id %}
          {% get_protective_measures_count_with_same_danger_id assessment_activity.assessment_protective_measures.all assessment_protective_measure.danger.id as protective_measures_count %}

          <td
            rowspan="{{ protective_measures_count }}"
            style="padding: 4px; max-width: 200px; width: 200px;"
          >
            {{ assessment_protective_measure.danger.name }}
          </td>
          {% if assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk == 1 %}
            <td
              rowspan="{{ protective_measures_count }}"
              style="background-color: #5aa800; padding: 4px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 35px; min-width: 35px; max-width: 35px;"
            >
              {{ assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk }}
            </td>
          {% elif assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk == 2 %}
            <td
              rowspan="{{ protective_measures_count }}"
              style="background-color: #f1c02e; padding: 4px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 35px; min-width: 35px; max-width: 35px;"
            >
              {{ assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk }}
            </td>
          {% elif assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk == 3 %}
            <td
              rowspan="{{ protective_measures_count }}"
              style="background-color: #f12e49; padding: 4px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 35px; min-width: 35px; max-width: 35px;"
            >
              {{ assessment_protective_measure.danger.risk }}
            </td>
          {% endif %}
        {% endifchanged %}

        <td style="padding: 4px;">
          {{ assessment_protective_measure.protective_measure.description }}
        </td>

        {% if forloop.first %}
          <td
            rowspan="{{ assessment_activity.assessment_protective_measures.all.count }}"
            style="padding: 4px; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;"
          >
            {% if assessment_activity.activity.applicable_regulations %}
              {{ assessment_activity.activity.applicable_regulations }}
            {% else %}
              {{ "" }}
            {% endif %}
          </td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if assessment_protective_measure.effective %}
          <td style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 4px; width: 30px; min-width: 30px; max-width: 30px;">
            &#10003;
          </td>
          <td style="padding: 4px; width: 30px; min-width: 30px; max-width: 30px;">
            {{ "" }}
          </td>
        {% else %}
          <td style="padding: 4px; width: 30px; min-width: 30px; max-width: 30px;">
            {{ "" }}
          </td>
          <td style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 4px; width: 30px; min-width: 30px; max-width: 30px;">
            &#10003;
          </td>
        {% endif %}

        <td style="padding: 4px; width: 86px; min-width: 86px; max-width: 86px;">
          {{ "" }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```